# Ошибка после сборки maven проекта

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, jar, executable

Написал для себя программу, которая работает с сетью. В idea работает без каких-либо проблем, а вот после сборки проекта и запуска через cmd ловлю следующие ошибки.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вот `pom.xml`:**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>8.8.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.dongliu</groupId>
        <artifactId>requests</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180130</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что при исполнении вашего jar-файла, вы не задаете правильный [classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).
Чтобы все заработало, вам необходимо указать пути для всех ваших зависимостей в classpath.
Как вариант, можно использовать [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/), который собирает jar файл со всеми зависимостями внутри.
А по поводу того, что из Idea все работает - это потому что Idea автоматически задает правильный classpath, когда вы запускаете вашу программу из нее.

Comment: Вставил вот такой плагин, но ошибка та же <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>ru.myproj.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

Comment: См. пример http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html раздел "Execution: Building an Assembly"

Answer (score 0):

Хотя IntelliJ IDEA и позволяет создавать jar файлы вместе с зависимостями, но лучше использовать проверенные решения с помощью onejar.

Вы можете использовать [onejar-maven-plugin](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.jolira/onejar-maven-plugin/1.4.4/maven-plugin) для сборки выполняемого модуля.