# Как запустить тесты из main метода

Tags: java, maven, junit

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как запустить тесты JUnit из main() метода в maven проекте?
я пытался таким образом:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JUnitCore.main("com.example.MyTest");
}
```

но вылетает ошибка, что не удается найти указанный класс.

Comment: Зачем это надо? Мавен сам запускает тесты

Comment: хочу создать executable jar

Comment: Если нехватает зависимостей, то можно использоват [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/916031/204920) решение